# The type initializer for '...Helpers.Helpers' threw an exception. in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in ...Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for '...Helpers.Helpers' threw an exception.
```

the error comes in

```
 string ff = MFI.Helpers.Helpers.GetConfigSetting("ZenDesk_OrganizationMembers");
```

this is GetConfigSetting:

```
 public static string GetConfigSetting(string settingName)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName];
        }
```

In GetConfigSetting i got null value...how to solve??

Comment: use a null coalescing operator in your `GetConfigSetting` method, turning it into this `return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName] ?? "";` This will do exactly what it did before, but if the value is null, it will instead return a blank string

Comment: sounds like you need to look at the `Helpers.Helpers` class or `MFI` whatever that is and actually initialize that object can you show more relevant code..?